# Sonar Link not enabled in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run a job in Jenkins for sonar analysis(Using *"Invoke standalone Sonar analysis"* option) which refreshes the view in Sonar Dashboard , but sonar link is not enabled in Jenkins even after the build is successful. Console of Jenkins shows links to all the views of the Sonar dashboard which is not the expected output.

**SonarQube version - 5.6** (LTS version)
**Sonar runner - 2.8** (official documentation of SonarQube says this version is compatible with LTS version)
**Jenkins used - 1.554**

I had tried almost with all possible sonar scanner/runner versions available but no luck.Please help me on this!!

Thanks in advance :)

***Please check the console which is updating all the views in the Sonarqube.***

INFO: SonarQube Server 5.6.6
00:46:09.873 INFO  - Load global repositories
00:46:10.456 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=585ms
00:46:10.471 INFO  - Server id: xxxxxxx
00:46:10.483 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
00:46:10.484 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
00:46:10.484 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
00:46:10.486 INFO  - User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
00:46:10.865 INFO  - Load plugins index
00:46:10.887 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=22ms
00:46:11.777 INFO  - governance licensed, PRODUCTION_GLOBAL
00:46:11.785 INFO  - Trigger Views update
00:46:12.463 INFO  - Following views updates have been successfully submitted:
00:46:12.463 INFO  -   *  http://localhost.she.pwj.com:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVrQSaXCM-vkk86yLw-C
00:46:12.464   INFO  -   * http://localhost.she.pwj.com:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVrQSaXoM-vkk86yLw-D

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3.849s
Final Memory: 7M/53M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the a snippet of the analysis log showing the bad link (feel free to obscure the domain if you like).

Comment: Added the console output of the job.

Comment: Please also add the analysis command you used.

Comment: Project properties  : sonar.views.list=total-views ( "total-views" is the key of the view which I had created in Sonar dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

Views regeneration is not like project analysis. Project analysis updates a *single* project, thus the analysis log can provide you a link to the single project in question. Views regeneration updates *all* views. What you're seeing in the logs is the links to the relevant background tasks. You can follow those tasks to know when regeneration is complete. But viewing a background task is a privileged operation. If you cannot successfully follow the links in the view regeneration log, it means that either you're not logged in or your privileges are insufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not face any such problems in our previous Previous _SonarQube versions(4.5.4)_.Whenever a views job is run it just gives the corresponding _sonar link_ of the view of in the console after the build is successful.But in this case **neither the sonar link is provided in the console nor the Sonar link is getting enabled in the job's home page** even after the build is shown as successful.